# How does Shingo's use of "osu" in this particular dialogue differ from its use elsewhere?

Tags: japanese-language, osu-karatebu

In the manga [*Osu!! Karatebu*](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=43102) the word "osu" is used quite frequently, and from context I have so far assumed that it is a way for the junior members of the karate club to respond to their seniors in a general "yes, sir" way. However, I recently came across this panel which presents a quite different take on the word:

[image: Morigami Shingo on "osu"]

What is the significance of Shingo's particular dialogue about "osu?" Is it a typical philosophy of the character, karate, or a mix of the two? Why is it so different from how it is used elsewhere in the manga?

Comment: I don't think this is on topic here...

Comment: @ton.yeung Why not? From looking at the related questions, there seems to be quite a few on similar topics? E.g. [this one](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/what-does-tsukkomi-mean?rq=1)

Comment: I've heard discussions on whether what x means is related to anime or just the japanese language, the former would be on topic, and the later would not

Comment: But this is in relation to the manga mentioned in the question? Have you got some suggestions on how I could edit it to make this more clear? @ton.yeung

Comment: If you are asking about the usage of the word, then it's off-topic and a question for [Japanese.SE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com). If you are asking about what he means in regards to the context of the manga, then it is on-topic. The line here is a bit thin in regards to Japanese language questions. Please word your question accordingly.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify what I ask about - if it is still off-topic, could someone please flag it for migration? @ʞɹɐzǝɹ

Comment: The scope of your question is a bit ambiguous after the edit. Are you now asking about the philosophy of the word in regards to the characters or the significance of the word in regards to the manga in general? I'd like you to clear up this point to prevent any possible misunderstandings.

Comment: How it is used in the manga basically - in the example shown, it seems to be pretty evident that it is about the philosophy, but is that also why they use it at other points in the manga? It doesn't really seem that way, but I may be missing something. @ʞɹɐzǝɹ

Comment: A better way to go about this question is to ask what you don't understand about the dialogue and not make any presumption on the meaning of part of it. If people have trouble understand your question then they would obviously have trouble answering it. Try to be as direct as possible.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Pretty much rewrote the question to clarify what confuses me, trying to stick to the guidelines you set - do you think it is easier to understand now?

Answer (score 1):

You make an overly broad assumption with this particular word. "Ossu" here is talked about not as a salutation here, but for a deeper more philosophical meaning in general.

Ossu, is made of of two kanji:

[押]{おっ} and [忍]{す}. 押 by itself loosely translates to the action of apply pressure to something, such as pushing. 忍 means endurance or restraint.

The dialogue by the character here breaks down the literal meaning of the word and uses the two kanji as a philosophy of sorts. It's like using the word embodiment of a word as a sort of ambition or goal to live by.

In this case the spirit of Ossu is made up of these two kanji. The meaning here is to apply them meaning of those to your own life and when you use them remember their meaning so that it may carry you further, whenever or wherever you may need it, like a mantra.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Would those two kanji be the ones translated as "oshi" and "shinobu" [here](http://www.australiankyokushin.com/osu.shtml)? And is this also the meaning the word carries when the word is used elsewhere, or does it simply carry multiple meanings, as it doesn't *seem* to carry that much meaning most of the time? Anyway, I am going to leave the question open for a while to see if any other explanations appears, but if no better answer comes forth, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: "Ossu" is like a portmanteau, much like how “squawk” is made up of squall and squeak. In this case (in regards to martial arts, especially karate), it's "osu" (to push) and "shinobu" (to endure/hide) It's not how you read the individual kanji, but rather what happens when you mesh them together. How one interprets this compound kanji derives its symbolism/philosophy. It can mean a number of things to a number of people.

Comment: Karate (especially Kyokushin Karate) requires extreme amounts of physical conditioning and guts so there exists a theory says that if you shout “osu!” as you train, you verbally condition yourself to break out of your comfort zone and push your mind and body to the limit .